# Autodesk Forge :: Error 404 on localhost:3000

Tags: php, autodesk-forge

I'm trying to make this tutorial (from here [Forge : View your models](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/environment/rundebug/2legged) )(php) and i'm getting blank page with HTTP Error 404, any idea ?
nothing in debugger, nothing enywhere else...
When calling this uri http://localhost:3000/api/forge/oss/buckets i get this error

```
( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: id in D:\ArMediaCG\www\...\AutoCad API Extention\apps\Forge\first_tutorial\server\oss.php on line 54
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.8060  405488  {main}( )   ...\index.php:0
2   0.8591  519816  Klein\Klein->dispatch( )    ...\index.php:50
3   0.8661  552248  Klein\Klein->handleRouteCallback( ) ...\Klein.php:572
4   0.8661  552248  call_user_func:{D:\ArMediaCG\www\...\AutoCad API Extention\apps\Forge\first_tutorial\vendor\klein\klein\src\Klein\Klein.php:859} ( )    ...\Klein.php:859
5   0.8661  552248  {closure:D:\ArMediaCG\www\...\AutoCad API Extention\apps\Forge\first_tutorial\index.php:27-30}( )   ...\Klein.php:859
6   0.8661  552288  Autodesk\ForgeServices\DataManagement->getBucketsAndObjects( )  ...\index.php:29

( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Missing the required parameter $bucket_key when calling getObjects in D:\ArMediaCG\www\...\AutoCad API Extention\apps\Forge\first_tutorial\vendor\klein\klein\src\Klein\Klein.php on line 925
( ! ) Klein\Exceptions\UnhandledException: Missing the required parameter $bucket_key when calling getObjects in D:\ArMediaCG\www\...\AutoCad API Extention\apps\Forge\first_tutorial\vendor\klein\klein\src\Klein\Klein.php on line 925
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.8060  405488  {main}( )   ...\index.php:0
2   0.8591  519816  Klein\Klein->dispatch( )    ...\index.php:50
3   0.8751  667432  Klein\Klein->error( )   ...\Klein.php:629
```

After trying localhost:3000/www/index.html with debug i got this `Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference` on line 65 of oss.php file. I've also noticed that tokens and old buckets are loaded
[image: debug]

Comment: This exception is triggered because `bucket_key` wasnt supplied to the call.  Its weird tho since the sample does infact handle this exception. Can you show the relevant code behind this ?

Comment: Hi thank you, not sure how i can get that id, i'm doing this code [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.viewmodels/tree/php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's a solution, let's try :
When going to localhost/www/ it shows the page but don't load anything, in oss.php at line 65 i've replaced that line with these ones :

```
$cbkeyParts = explode('-', $cbkey);
$cbtext = ForgeConfig::$prepend_bucketkey && strpos($cbkey, strtolower(ForgeConfig::getForgeID())) === 0 ? end($cbkeyParts) : $cbkey;
```

the `end(explode('-', $cbkey));` makes an error and the explode function should be remove and replaced with a variable.

Now to use simply localhost:3000 instead of add the /www/index.html, it looks like .htaccess rewrite rules are not working on php server with VS Code, so i tryed with apache and still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Like Samuel pointed in the comments the bucket key was not supplied to the backend handler and hence the error.

But actually the frontend does not handle empty/incorrect bucket key input and hence the error was called out in the backend ... You can implement your own (check if the bucket key entered is valid) if you like [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.viewmodels/blob/php/www/js/ForgeTree.js#L61) to catch empty input ...

Comment: Hi thank you, but not sure how i can get that id, i'm using the code you sent me to [here](Hi thank you, not sure how i can get that id, i'm doing this code [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.viewmodels/tree/php). Also, i'm not sure which url should i call

Comment: I've just used the dot NET code and got the UI working well, i found there two buckets created with the php version, but php never showed them (not that i used the /www/index.html in php to create those buckets, i'm confused how the html created them and didnt get them, show a loading icon indefinitely)

Comment: Interessting Bryan, i was wondering why the error messages where different from those defined in the try catch statements. This explains alot. Cheers